# How to solve E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout after after percelize the fragment?

Tags: android-studio

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my build.gradle? How can I solve the error?
I have tried a lot to solve this problem but failed all the time. Please someone help me to solve this error.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

**Database**

```
package com.example.noteapp.DataBase

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.noteapp.dao.NotesDao
import com.example.noteapp.model.Notes

@Database(entities = [Notes::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class NotesDataBase : RoomDatabase() {

     abstract fun myNotesDao(): NotesDao

     companion object{
         @Volatile
         var INSTANCE : NotesDataBase ?= null;

         fun getDataBaseInstance(context: Context) : NotesDataBase {
             val tempInstance = INSTANCE
             if (tempInstance != null){
                 return tempInstance
             }
             synchronized(this)
             {
                 val roomDatabaseInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, NotesDataBase::class.java, "Notes").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                 INSTANCE = roomDatabaseInstance
                 return roomDatabaseInstance

             }


         }

     }

}
```

**This is the previous Note Model**

```
package com.example.noteapp.model

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "Notes")
class Notes (@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
      var id : Int? = null,
      var title : String,
      var notes : String,
      var date : String,
            // need to percelize color var color: Int = -1,
      ) : Parcelable {
      constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readValue(Int::class.java.classLoader) as? Int,
            parcel.readString().toString(),
            parcel.readString().toString(),
            parcel.readString().toString(),
      ) {
      }

      override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            parcel.writeValue(id)
            parcel.writeString(title)
            parcel.writeString(notes)
            parcel.writeString(date)
      }

      override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
      }

      companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Notes> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Notes {
                  return Notes(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Notes?> {
                  return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
      }
}
```

**New Note Model**

```
package com.example.noteapp.model

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "Notes")
class Notes (@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
      var id : Int? = null,
      var title : String,
      var notes : String,
      var date : String,
      var color : Int = -1,
          
      ) : Parcelable {
      constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readValue(Int::class.java.classLoader) as? Int,
            parcel.readString().toString(),
            parcel.readString().toString(),
            parcel.readString().toString(),
            parcel.readInt()
      ) {
      }

      override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            parcel.writeValue(id)
            parcel.writeString(title)
            parcel.writeString(notes)
            parcel.writeString(date)
            parcel.writeInt(color)
      }

      override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
      }

      companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Notes> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Notes {
                  return Notes(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Notes?> {
                  return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is something wrong with your `build.gradle` file.

But As I can see that error

```
Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

in your logcat

It means you have changed something in your `Room database` but not changed the version of database. Either try changing the version of Database or Uninstall the app from your device and rerun your project.

Always remember that you have to change the version of `RoomDB` every time if you change something in database. Otherwise, it will throw exception.

I hope the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I added my database and model to the question. can you see those to find out what's wrong? my previous note model was fine. but when I add "var color: Int = -1" to the "New Note Model" and percelize it again then this error came. Right can you tell what should i do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is what I am saying if you are trying to run your app in the same device please try changing the version of your database or uninstall the previously installed app from your device. Your database version is 1 and it can be the reason that you are getting the same error

Comment: Always post your logcat it will help others to understand your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I understand the reason of the error. May Allah bless you. Assalamualaikum 